# How to move the "find" box in SQL 17?

Tags: sql

Apologies if this is out of bounds since it refers to programming, but it's not really a programming question.

I recently upgraded to SQL 17 and I can't work out how to move the "find" box (Ctrl + F, etc). The old "find" box could be dragged around the screen and repositioned however the user liked.  This one seems to generate at the top-right-hand of the screen and stubbornly stay there, obscuring the portion of the code which is in this area.

I feel like this may be a thick question, but I can't work out how to move the box around the screen.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: This question also applies to Visual Studio, so you could have asked on Stack Overflow where questions about programming tools are on-topic. However, it's still on-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean SQL Server Management Studio 17, and you get a find dialog like this:

[image: Default find dialog]

Click on the circled dropdown and choose "Find in Files..." and you will get a movable dialog:

[image: Movable dialog]

You mention "the portion of the code which is in this area" so you may want to make sure that "Look in" is set to "Current document", as circled above.

They could perhaps have chosen a better name for it than "Find in Files".

Comment: Super - thanks. 

A bit of a kerfuffle!  Not sure what was wrong with the old search function...